# BottlePy has invalid syntax?

Tags: python-2.7, mod-wsgi, bottle

I am trying to use BottlePy behind Apache with mod_wsgi.

app.wsgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/python27
from bottle import route, default_app
from wbem.models import Host

@route('/')
def index():
    return "Home Page"

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
application = default_app()
```

However, I seem to get this error:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=8850): Target WSGI script '/u/apps/wbem/app.wsgi' cannot be loaded as     Python module.
[Wed Oct 30 09:35:17 2013] [error] [client 10.10.65.19] mod_wsgi (pid=8850): Exception   occurred processing WSGI script '/u/apps/wbem/app.wsgi'.
[Wed Oct 30 09:35:17 2013] [error] [client 10.10.65.19] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Oct 30 09:35:17 2013] [error] [client 10.10.65.19]   File "/u/apps/wbem/app.wsgi", line 2, in ?
[Wed Oct 30 09:35:17 2013] [error] [client 10.10.65.19]     from bottle import route, default_app
[Wed Oct 30 09:35:17 2013] [error] [client 10.10.65.19]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bottle.py", line 113
[Wed Oct 30 09:35:17 2013] [error] [client 10.10.65.19]      return s.encode(enc) if isinstance(s, unicode) else bytes(s)
[Wed Oct 30 09:35:17 2013] [error] [client 10.10.65.19]                            ^
[Wed Oct 30 09:35:17 2013] [error] [client 10.10.65.19]  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If some guru could shed some light, would appreciate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mod_wsgi is using an old version of Python (2.4 or earlier).  You need to either rebuild mod_wsgi with this:

```
./configure --with-python=/usr/local/python27
```

or (but see EDIT below) move your python27 executable to its own directory (IMO a better practice, anyway), and then include this in your apache wsgi config:

```
WSGIPythonHome /usr/local/bin/python2.7 # directory of your Python 2.7
```

More details available [here](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Multiple_Python_Versions).

Hope this helps!

---

EDIT: Per GrahamDumpleton's comment, setting WSGIPythonHome isn't necessarily helpful here.  My understanding is that it's designed to solve a slightly different problem form yours: to tell mod_wsgi where its python installation is when it's in a nonstandard location (i.e., one which wouldn't normally be on the `PATH` that Apache gets).

Comment: I'm going to say you're right :) Just having an argument with management around Python versions etc. *sigh* - Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks.  And sorry to hear that your problem has shifted from an easy technical problem to a thorny people problem. :) Cheers!

Comment: You cannot use WSGIPythonHome to force mod_wsgi to use a different Python run time version than what it was compiled for. It will forever be hard wired to the version it was compiled for and would need to be recompiled against the correct Python version. So, you cannot force mod_wsgi to use Python 2.7 if it was compiled for Python 2.4. Your second suggestions is therefore questionable in this context.

Comment: Thanks Graham.  I'll edit my answer to reflect that.